# Google Compute Engine SSH Keys new UI and requirement (which user email?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

Today, I just noted that the SSH user I have added to the VM are not there anymore. I have to regenerate the keys and add in the user again but the user interface and requirement of SSH key has changed. The last time I generate a SSH key was only 1 month ago. What triggered the change?

Using the previous method, I got this error. I am confused which user email to provide? The email of the instance owner or the email of the SSH key user? I tried both but none of that is working.

Instead of email address, is there a way to use a name for SSH user?

```
Invalid key. Required format: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com> or <protocol> <key-blob> google-ssh {"userName":"<username@example.com>","expireOn":"<date>"}
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted or upvoted for greater visibility for community members.

Answer (score 0):

The username used while creating the SSH key is to be used when adding the SSH key to metadata.There is some [Public Issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/175796497) while adding SSH keys via New UI console and the Product Engineering team is working on this Cloud console issue. So in the meantime,As a workaround use the gcloud commands to modify the instance or try modifying the keys( by including the username at the end) to comply with the format.

Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#gcloud_1) for adding SSH keys via gcloud commands.